# How to Mock inner methods in GoLang

Tags: go, gomock

e.g

```
type test struct { // few fields}
func (t *test) createresource(res1 string,res2 string)error {
     //doing some task

     t.createsubresource(res1)
}

func (t *test)createsubresource(res1 string)error{
    //perform some task
}
```

I want to write test function for createresource , how can I mock   t.createsubresource(res1) call. This is legacy code and I don't have permission to modify any above function.

Comment: You cannot. Stop that mocking business, it doesn't work well in Go. If you need a special test double for createsubresource than you will have to modify test to accomodate for switching that (e.g. via an interface).

Comment: Can you please provide example ?

Comment: E.g. as a field in the test struct: `type test struct {... csr func(res1 string) ...}` which points to the real implementation and can be switched to an appropriate test double if needed.

Comment: Got it ,In my case I don't have provision to change the existing code block.

Answer (score 6):

Your mock can be done using [interfaces](https://golangbot.com/interfaces-part-1/), as for example:

**main.go**

```golang
package main

type TestInterface interface {
    CreateResource(res1 string, res2 string) error
    CreateSubresource (res1 string) error
}

func main() {
    DoSomething(new(Test))   
}

func DoSomething(t TestInterface) {
    t.CreateResource()
}
```

**main_test.go**

```
package main

import "testing"

type TestMock struct {}

func (tm *TestMock) CreateResource(res1 string, res2 string) error {
    return nil
}

func (tm *TestMock) CreateSubresource(res1 string) error {
    return nil
}

func TestDoSomething(t *testing.T) {
    err := DoSomething(new(TestMock))
    //... do your assertions
}
```

**Why does it works like that?**

Calling a function that depends on a specific structure does not allow you to inject alternatives to it, that's why a solution using interface needs to be created. By having an interface, just implement a new structure that matches that interface and pass it as a [dependency injection](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/a-quick-intro-to-dependency-injection-what-it-is-and-when-to-use-it-7578c84fa88f/) to the procedure that will be tested.

**Also, check this out:**

- There is no easy way, by default, to just point your original structure and tell Go to make a mock from it. Maybe some 3rd party lib can do it (but I didn't saw that yet).
- In go, [public and private declarations](https://yourbasic.org/golang/public-private/) are defined by the first letter as uppercase. By the lower cases declarations in your sample I've noticed that everything is private.
- Usually it is not a good practice to test private methods. There are a lot of discussions about this topic, you can take a look in [this one here](https://dzone.com/articles/why-shouldnt-i-test-private)
- There are also some support libs to make assertions and mocks like for example [stretchr/testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify), please make a research first.

I hope that it helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed information @Marcel